# Why Type mismatch error is thrown up when F in "(F obj)" is replaced with Factory. What is F at compile time

Tags: java

Why Type mismatch error is thrown up when F in "(F obj)" is replaced with Factory. What is F at compile time, is it Object or just F while compilation.

```
interface Factory<T>
{
    T create();
}

class FirstClass<T>
{
    T x;
    <F extends Factory<T>> FirstClass(F obj)// Error will be thrown when F in (F obj)                                                  
                                            // is replaced with Factory. Error will be
                                            // cannot convert from "Object to T"
    {
        x = obj.create();
    }
}


class integerFactory implements Factory<Integer>
{

    @Override
    public Integer create() {

        return 1000;
    }

}

public class testGenerics {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new FirstClass<Integer>(new integerFactory());
    }

}
```

Comment: `Factory`, and not `Factory<T>`?

Comment: Please also show us the code that doesn't compile.

Comment: Yes. Factory<T> will work fine but why Type mismatch error occurs when we use only Factory

Comment: I have commented the line in the code which throws compilation error when (F obj) is replaced with (Factory obj)

Answer (score 0):

The compilation error is for the statement `x = obj.create();`.

This is because `Factory` is a [raw type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.8):

> The reference type that is formed by taking the name of a generic type declaration without an accompanying type argument list.

A raw type is the [erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.6) of its parameterized type.

The erasure of a type variable (such as `T`) [is its left-most bound](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.4):

> If no bound is declared for a type variable, Object is assumed.

Therefore, the method `create` of the raw type `Factory` returns `Object`.

We do not know what `T` is inside `FirstClass<T>`, so we do not know if `Object` can be assigned to it.

See also:

- [Raw Types Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html)
- [Type Erasure Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html)
- [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it)